# ScrollView in pageView

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have pageView where in the bottom of each page there is a scrollView.
I want that the pageView doesn't turn when the scrollView is scrolling.
My problem is:
when I scroll (in the scrollView) the pages turn with him!

Answer (score 1):

This may not a good practice but it can solve your problem: in Xcode go to your project/ cocos2d_libs.xcodeproject/ extensions/ GUI/ CCScrollView

In CCScrollView.h add:

```
void mySetSwallowTouch(bool enabled);
```

In CCScrollView.cpp add:

```
void ScrollView::mySetSwallowTouch(bool enabled) {
_touchListener->setSwallowTouches(enabled);}
```

Now call mySetSwallowTouch(true) at your scrollview

```
scrollview->mySetSwallowTouch(true);
```

You can also use this with your table view inside a pageView

Answer (score 1):

Since cocos2d-x v3.3 there is already a method `void mySetSwallowTouch(bool enabled)` available for ListView.

You can simply use it:

```
ListView* listView = ListView::create();
listView->setSwallowTouches(true);
```

BTW, I believe swallow touches is currently set to `true` for ListView by default.